# JavaFX setCellValueFactory Method Calling More Times

Tags: java, javafx, callback

I've created a tableView. But its setCellValueFactory methods calling two or more times. And it causes a bug. What can be reason of this? Below, my Person and Controller classes.

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

private final SimpleStringProperty name;
private final SimpleStringProperty surname;
private final SimpleStringProperty job;
private final BooleanProperty isSelected;

public Person(SimpleStringProperty name, SimpleStringProperty surname, SimpleStringProperty job,
        BooleanProperty isSelected) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.job = job;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public SimpleStringProperty getName() {
    return name;
}

public SimpleStringProperty getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public SimpleStringProperty getJob() {
    return job;
}

public BooleanProperty getIsSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
private final TableView<Person> fxPersonTableView;

@FXML
private final TableColumn<Person, Boolean> fxSelectColumnCheckbox;

@FXML
private final TableColumn<Person, String> fxNameTableColumn;

@FXML
private final TableColumn<Person, String> fxSurnameTableColumn;

@FXML
private final TableColumn<Person, String> fxJobTableColumn;

List<Person> persons;

private void createTableView(){

    fxSelectColumnCheckbox.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(fxSelectColumnCheckbox));

    //fxSelectColumnCheckbox.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().getIsSelected()); I'm using this, but for print wrote below

    fxSelectColumnCheckbox.setCellValueFactory(c -> {

        System.out.println("METHOD: fxSelectColumnCheckbox.setCellValueFactory"); // This is printed two or more times.
        return c.getValue().getIsSelected());

    });

    fxNameTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> persons.get(c).getName());
    fxSurnameTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> persons.get(c).getSurname());
    fxJobTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> persons.get(c).getJob());
    fxPersonTableView.getSelectionModel.setSleectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    fxPersonTableView.setItems(persons);

}
}
```

Comment: Which methods are called multiple times? Your `setCellFactory(...)` methods will be called once for each time `createTableView()` is callled

Comment: fxSelectColumnCheckbox.setCellValueFactory method called multiple times. I call createTableView() once but it call two times setCellValueFactory method. It prints two times "METHOD:..." It is the problem.

Comment: The callback you pass to `setCellFactory` will be invoked every time a cell needs to know what value to display. So at the beginning it will be invoked once for each non-empty visible cell in the column (it *has* to be invoked multiple times with different items being passed as the parameter, to represent different rows). Subsequently, it may be invoked if the cell is reused for a different item (e.g. if the user scrolls). This is the designed behavior and there is no way to prevent it; you need to write your code on the understanding that this will happen.

Comment: I understood, thank you... @James_D

Comment: I have the same problem. plz share the solution